# Please explain this specific line in my Java Code?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, java

I have just started learning Java and I reached till arrays , I was preparing this program(From a book) on replacing space ' ' with '.' (dots) and i am not able to understand this specific line (its not mentioned even in the book I am learning from).

Please help me out.

```
class SpaceRemover{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String mostFamous = "Hey there stackoverFLow     ";
        char [] mf1 = mostFamous.toCharArray();
        for(int dex = 0; dex<mf1.length;dex++)
        {
            char current = mf1[dex];   // What is happening in this line ??
            if (current != ' ') {
                System.out.print(current);

            }
            else{
                System.out.print('.');

            }
        }
        System.out.println();


        }
    }
```

Someone please explain what is happening in "char current = mf1[dex];"

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: These will help understand it clearly: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a String in java is an array of characters. So what the above code does is converts the string to an array of chars so that it can access each index of the array later on. Then the code enters into a for loop in order to iterate through all the indecies of the char array.

Assuming that that is already clear to you, the code now creates a char variable which holds the current index of the array.

```
char current = mf1[dex];
```

mf1 is your char array that represents the string. dex is the current index of the char that is determined by the for loop. So by doing this we can check each character (letter) of the char array. Now if the char "current" is a blank space we can replace it with a dot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the really good explanation. I have written down your answer... It made me understand the concept really good. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the `dex`th character/item within the character array `mf1` (hence `mf1[dex]`) and storing it into the local variable `current`.

Answer (score 0):

It's getting the character at index `idx` in the array `mf1` and storing its value in the `current` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop is iterating the string `mostFamous` character by character.

the line you are asking is to get the character at specific position. Function is similar to JavaScript's [charAt(i)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

Answer (score 0):

After this statement, `char [] mf1 = mostFamous.toCharArray();`

```
mf1[0]=H, mf1[1]=e, mf1[1]=y...
```

so at this line, `char current = mf1[dex];`
so, in first iteration, `current=H`, second iteration `current=e...`

Answer (score 0):

```
char current = mf1[dex];
```

This line gets values from the `mf1` char array and assign to the `current` variable  according to the `dex`, `dex` works as index to the array element and it increments with the running loop.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
char current = mf1[dex];
```

is placed inside a for loop where the variable dex is incremented each time the loop is iterated. The variable `dex` is the zero-based index of the array. On the left hand side of the assignment operator (=), you are declaring a variable named `current` of type `char`. On the right hand side of the assignment operator you are accessing the dex-th character of your CharArray, if you start counting from zero. The assignment operator binds the variable you declared with the value of the character you specified on the right hand side.

For example, the first time the loop is run, `dex` would start at 0, hence `mf1[dex]` (or `mf1[0]`) is just 'H'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```
class SpaceRemover{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String mostFamous = "Hey there stackoverFLow     ";

            char [] mf1 = mostFamous.toCharArray();

            // mf1 contains={'H', 'e','y',' ','t','h',.........}

            for(char current: mf1)

            {

         //the for-each loop assigns the value of mf1 variable to the current variable

                //At first time the 'H' is assigned to the current and so-on

                System.out.print(current==' '?'.':current );

            }

            System.out.println();



            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It assigns the element of the `char` array `mf1` at the index `dex` to the `char` variable `current`.

Note that the for loop and that line may be simplified by using the `foreach` syntax; these two code blocks are equivalent:

```
// Your code
for(int dex = 0; dex<mf1.length;dex++) {
    char current = mf1[dex]; 

// Equivalent code
for (char current : mf1) {
```

But further, the whole method may be replaced by one line:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hey there stackoverFLow     ".replace(" ", "."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char current = mf1[dex];
```

this will return the char element in char array whose index is dex

This is quite a basic usage of array.

Good luck with your study.

Comment: Thank you sir.
Yes I will do my best. :)